# Gathering statistics in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm looking for a program that can log the use of / gather statistics in Dragon NaturallySpeaking, such as the following:

- Use of commands (e.g. log `command name, timestamp`)
- Use of words (e.g. log `word`, `timestamp`)
- Use of the correction menu.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking Professional 12.5 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I am aware of that the recognition history is available as a built-in feature but it's reset each time a user profile is reloaded and it is a pain to have to save it manually all the time.

Comment: If anyone has any idea please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: could you write a script that does that for you? Like "copy the history file - then start the program" - That way you would use the build in feature and not have the pain to do it manually.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Yes I had written one but I find it to be a pain to use because I typically leave Dragon opens all the time and only restart it when it crashes by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script to save the speech recognition history when close Dragon NaturallySpeaking. Not such a great solution but the only thing I found so far.

```
Sub Main

    SetMicrophone 0
    HeardWord "view","recognition","history"
    Wait 1
    SendSystemKeys "{Alt+d}"
    Wait 1
    timeStamp = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hhmmss")
    filePath = "C:\RecogHistory\" & timeStamp
    SendSystemKeys filePath
    Wait 1
    SendSystemKeys "{Enter}"
    Wait 1
    HeardWord "switch","to","DragonBar"
    Wait 2
    SendSystemKeys "{Alt+F4}"
    Wait 1

End Sub
```

[image]